# RStudio shiny datatables save csv unquoted?

Tags: datatables, shiny, rstudio

How can I save the output of an RStudio Shiny DataTables table using the `Save` to `CSV` extension, but have the content saved unquoted instead of the default, which is in double-quotes:

For example, for a single column with two entries, I get a `file.csv` like this:

```
"column_name"
"foo"
"bar"
```

And instead I would like either:

```
column_name
foo
bar
```

Or even better, without the header:

```
foo
bar
```

My current code looks like this:

```
output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
  entries()
  }, options = list(colnames = NULL, bPaginate = FALSE,
    "sDom" = 'RMDT<"cvclear"C><"clear">lfrtip',
             "oTableTools" = list(
                     "sSwfPath" = "copy_csv_xls.swf",
                     "aButtons" = list(
                               "copy",
                               "print",
                               list("sExtends" = "collection",
                                                   "sButtonText" = "Save",
                                                   "aButtons" = list("csv","xls")
                                              )
                             )
                   )
   )
)
```

EDIT:

I tried with one of the suggested answers, and `ajax` is not allowed, the page complains when I click on SaveTXT. If I do the following, it still puts things within double quotes:

```
                             list("sExtends" = "collection",
                                                 "sButtonText" = "SaveTXT",
                                                 "sFieldBoundary" = '',
                                                 "aButtons" = list("csv")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have there been any recent changes to dataTables extensions that will make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible through button options:[Button options](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options#sFieldBoundary)
And changing `sFieldBoundary` value.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "ajax",
                    "sFieldBoundary": '"'
                }
            ]
        }
    } );
} );
```

But I couldn't get it working in shiny.